# Connect Skype online [New-CsOnlineSession()] with MFA enable office admin using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, skype-for-business

To automate connection to skype online, I am trying to connect using **New-CsOnlineSession()** session command to execute **Get-CsOAuthConfiguration**.
And I want to run this script into Azure automation runbook. I am able to use Non-MFA office admin but when I try to use that script with MFA enable office admin script throwing an error regarding MFA.
Then I found office an App password approach in which we can create an **office app password** for MFA admin Id, That worked for SharePoint & Exchange PowerShell commands but not worked for Skype automation commands.

Is there any way to automate?